# How can user download database from django heroku?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I make a apllication in django. I want put a download button in the my aplicattion. User can download then in this button. In local host this work, but when i put in heroku don't.

listar.html:

```
<p>
   <form method="POST">
       <a href="{% url 'baixa' %}" download>Download</a>
   </form>
       <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'cadastrar_colecao' %}">Adicionar Novo</a>
</p>
```

urls.py:

```
urlspatterns = [
    path('download/',Download.Download,name='baixa'),
]
```

views.py:

```
class Download(TemplateView):

    def Download(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
        db_df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM formulario_colecao", conn)
        db_df.to_csv('formulario/colecao_UFMGAC.csv', index=False)
        return FileResponse(open('formulario/colecao_UFMGAC.csv', 'rb'), as_attachment=True)
```

In local host this work and my database system sqlite3. Heroku datase system is postgree. I want the any user can download the database from the button download.

So I need the button Download return csv file that contains datas.

Comment: are you uploading the database to heroku?

Comment: my database is not empty on heroku

Comment: You cannot reasonably use SQLite on Heroku. Changes to your database will be lost whenever your dyno restarts due to Heroku's ephemeral filesystem. One-off dynos, like the ones you get with `heroku run bash` or similar, get their _own_ ephemeral filesystem, which will include whatever version of the database was included in the application slug at build time. Drop SQLite and use a client-server database like PostgreSQL.

Comment: On Render (where I work) you can use a persistent disk and that would persist your SQLite data. But I have to say I agree with Chris, you are better off using a database like PostgreSQL. It's not quite easy in Django as flask-sqlalchemy but there are plenty of tutorials out there for migrating your data and schema from sqlite to Postgres if you need that, e.g. https://dev.to/thepylot/how-to-migrate-data-from-sqlite-to-postgresql-in-django-182h I wrote an blog that includes a spec for a Django app with a PostgreSQL app that might be helpful: https://render.com/blog/migrate-django-from-heroku

Answer (score 1):

To export the data from your Heroku Postgres database, create a new backup and download it.

```
heroku pg:backups:capture --app example-app
heroku pg:backups:download --app example-app
```

Refer official [heroku doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) for more

Comment: OP is using SQLite, not Heroku Postgres